# Removing non alpha characters in C

Tags: c, unix, replace, char

Is there an easy(ish) way to replace all non alpha characters from a character array with a space such as you might do with the bash command below?

sed 's/[^a-zA-Z]/ /g'

The only thing I can think of is to loop through the char array & do a compare & replace on a character by character basis.  I don't know if there is a C function that would do the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to do this that is better than O(n) anyways. Even if there was such a function or even a regex engine, it will probably less efficient than the simple linear complexity solution. You can just loop through the array and anything less than  'A' or greater than 'z' gets set to ' '.

```
while(*array)
{
  if(!isalpha(*array))
    *array = ' ';

  array++;
}
```

Comment: That was very helpful.  I ended up using something like `code
    i = 0;
    while (i < sizeof(word)) { 
      if (word[i] < 'A' || word[i] > 'z')
 word[i] = ' ';
      i++;
    }`\code`

Comment: You can use `!isalpha((unsigned char)*array)` as your test (`isalpha()` is declared in `<ctype.h>`).

Comment: @user2227422 I didn't know you could.

Comment: @user2227422 just use ` on both side of code. It will look like `this`.